# Microsoft Dynamics CRM 365: Millions of Contacts being generated for no apparent reason

Tags: dynamics-crm, crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-365

I wonder if the community out there can help with this.

We are using Microsoft Dynamics 365 v8.2.2.112, on-premises (not cloud).

The problem is this: millions – yes, literally millions – of Contacts are being created for no apparent reason.

Our users access CRM via an intranet page, but also using the CRM Outlook Plugin.

Since upgrading to v8.2 in January, something in CRM is creating millions of CRM Contacts.

The same Contact is being repeatedly re-created hundreds and thousands of times for the same user. And this happens for multiple Contacts and for multiple users. The end result is that millions of Contacts are being generated. The contact gets created every 5 minutes (approx).

You can easily see the Contacts being created. If you run an “Advanced Search” on Contact order by “created_on” descending order, you can see the same new Contact being generated every five minutes or so, and whose details exactly match the one created 5 minutes ago.

We’ve got about 20 users who seem to be particularly prolific Contact creators. Possibly because of the nature of their role, they add lots (ie dozens) of Contacts to Outlook (but they definitely don’t add hundreds of thousands of the same person!)

I'm absolutely baffled as to why this should happen.

The prevailing view at my company is that CRM Outlook synchronisation is to blame. We use the Outlook plugin widely. We use version 8.2.3.8 of the Outlook CRM plugin. When users sync their Outlook Contacts, maybe it doesn't recognise that the Contact is already in CRM, so regenerates it? We think it's a bug of that nature.

We can’t turn off Outlook synchronisation, because users require it in order to do their jobs. They need to be able to sync Activities, Emails, Contacts and so on.

We've checked all our custom code (C# plugins) to ensure that no Contacts are being create anywhere. We've especially checked the "on create" of Contacts to ensure it’s not creating an additional Contact. No code generates Contacts.

I understand that I am able to turn off users' Outlook Synchronisation filters. But I don’t want to do so as they do need to be able to sync with Outlook. It’s one of the reasons we use Dynamics CRM.

Does anybody know what’s causing this? Has anybody come across this before? What’s the solution to stop this happening? I'm after a root-cause if possible!

Comment: Did you try enabling Duplicate detection rule?

Comment: Thanks Arun, but the duplicate detection rule only handles 5000 records at a time. We're generating much more than that. Hence we're seeking a root-cause to the problem, so we can stop them getting generated in the first place.

Comment: Then probably a ticket with Microsoft can get you answer from PG team..

Answer (score 2):

Just wanted to keep this post up to date, for the benefit of any other poor souls who encounter this ghastly problem.

We were in touch with Microsoft who have been very helpful (although weren’t able to provide a “silver bullet” solution). The case is ongoing.

The first suggestion was that the problem was down to a customisation, integration or homemade plugin that had got itself into an endless loop, creating CRM Contacts ad infinitum. After searching absolutely every line of code and custom logic, I was able to confirm that the problem is not down to any of our customisations.

What we then did was to examine the Contacts being created on mass. We identified one Contact that was being generated over and over again. We checked its owner, let’s call this owner “John Smith”, and found that John Smith was the one creating this contact over and over. So we checked John Smith’s “Appointments, Contacts, and Tasks” syncing. We did this by “Settings -> Email Configuration -> Mailboxes”, then searched for John Smith’s mailbox. From John Smith’s mailbox, under the “Synchronization Method”, we set “Appointments, Contacts, and Tasks” from “Server-Side Synchronization” to “None”.

After doing this, the mass Contact generation immediately stopped. I’m not suggestion this is the solution to the problem (because we need to use syncing), but I am suggesting that this proves that the problem is down to a CRM bug in synchronisation (and not caused one of our customisations).

So if you’re getting this issue, and you want to rule out your customisations, I would follow these steps (above) to prove that it’s not your code that is responsible. If you turn off syncing for a user, and it stops generating millions of the same contacts owned by that user, I’d say you’ve got the same bug as me.

I think this bug is described in 2 possible places:
“Duplicate contacts are created if the rebuild of ID mapping fails after a test and enable.”: https://support.microsoft.com/en-in/help/4046463/service-update-9-for-microsoft-dynamics-365-8-2-1
OR 
“Contact synchronization that uses server-side synchronization causes infinite updates.”: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3203310/update-0-1-for-microsoft-dynamics-crm-2016-service-pack-1

The suggestion is that we’re getting this problem because we’ve not installed cumulative updates before installing a major version. I can’t agree that we were meant to. We installed the latest version as directed on-line. Obviously we can’t now install the updates which allegedly fix this bug, because we’re on a later version. We went from CRM 8.1.1.1005 to 8.2.2.0112 by skipping 2 cumulative versions (i.e. 8.2.0.0749 and 8.2.1.0176). It is alleged that these skipped versions had a bug fix for this issue in it (see link above), and by not installing them, this issue happened. I can’t really agree that it says anywhere to do this (install cumulative updates before installing a major version). Anyway, that’s the suggested cause of the issue.

Anyway, we’re still busy with the Microsoft guys. I’ll get back to you when there’s a definite course of action we can take. So it’s still work in progress.

We’re planning on deleting the millions of instances of that Contact from the user’s Outlook, then deleting the millions of that Contact from CRM (which has taken a week in a bulk delete), then we’re going to turn on “platform traces” (requiring a registry change), then we’re going to reactivate syncing, and gather the logs, and send them to Microsoft.

I’ll be back when there’s a definite solution.

Updated with a definite solution:
For the sake of completeness and in order to help anybody else who experiences this...

This nightmare was resolved by installing CRM patch v8.2.13.21. [NB We had been on v8.2.2.112] As soon as the patch was installed, the system ceased generated all these Contacts. They stopped being generated to the second!

We're still cleaning up the mess of the unwanted 20 million Contacts which shouldn't be there. But at least the issue is fixed.

I think the lesson is to keep your CRM system up to date in terms of patching!

Answer (score 0):

I faced similar issue in OnLine when we enabled outlook synchronization for Dynamics.
Even we had contacts been created randomly. If you look in advanced find for contacts  Created randomly it should be created by System user.

There is user setting in CRM as below and I think in your case **Automatically create records in Microsoft Dynamics 365** is set to YES

You will have to change this to No.

[image]

For other users you can use XRMToolBox plugin called User Setting Utility and there in you can see every user's personal setting as below

[image]

with the same XRM Tool Plugin you can bulk edit user personal setting as well

Comment: Thanks for replying. Alas this is not the answer. These Contacts aren't being created by the system user, Contacts are being created by regular CRM users (as can be seen from their “Created By”). Also, for a CRM user who is creating lots of Contacts, if I change their "Automatically create records in Microsoft Dynamics 365" setting to "No", then it makes no difference: the same Contact still get created over and over again every five minutes. In other words setting the "Automatically create records in Microsoft Dynamics 365" to "No" makes no difference at all. So alas, this isn't the solution.

Comment: so you say you did tired setting Automatically create records in Microsoft Dynamics 365" setting to "No" for most of the users and it did not changed anything?
you can try using advanced find and look for Email messages, I believe you might see Emails with status as "Received"
Reason if, for every Every Email received in CRM via outlook it looks for a Contact if not found it will create a new contact.

Comment: Thanks for answering. To answer your question, I set "Automatically create records in Microsoft Dynamics 365" to "No" for just _ONE_ user (eg) "John Smith". 
I have a Contact who is being created over and over again, who's "created by" is (eg) "John Smith". So I changed "John Smith"'s setting "Automatically create records in Microsoft Dynamics 365" to be "No". But despite doing this, the Contact is still being created over and over again. Not sure why changing everyone else's setting to "No" would stop the Contact being created (after all, "John Smith" is the person creating the Contact).

Comment: AnkUser, thanks for saying about the email. When I check I see no correlation between emails received and the same Contact being created over and over. Thanks for the info tho'.

Comment: Probably then I missed the point. I guess it is not what I expect.

Comment: Thanks for trying tho, AnkUser. Appreciate your attempt anyway.